Is my landlord allowed to invoke Innkeeper Act to enter my room whenever they want?
I'm renting a room in my cousin and her psycho husband's house in Ontario, there are shared living spaces, and they've given me a hard time over nonsense and invaded my privacy multiple times, always falling back on the innkeeper act and telling me that they can just kick me out without any warning whenever thye want, and using the fact I'm essentially living in fear to bully me into complying, even though I'm paying rent, and there's official forms on government record to prove it.
My question pertains to the fact that during another one of his psycho beligerent narcissistic outbreaks he told me that he needs a spare key to my room (I bought a replacement doorknob with a lock on it for my room because during a domestic dispute with one of his sons he broke the old knob and another one of his sons kept coming into my room without my permission when I was asleep, they refused to compensate me for the doorknob, explaining that they merely suggested that I buy a lock, not that I HAD to) so that he can get access to his books that are on a bookshelf in my room, as well as the router, which is also in my room. I complied because I know that landlords are supposed to get a spare key to your room in cases such as maintenance or an emergency, and I also assumed that since his books are in my room it might also mean that he's allowed to enter my room whenever he wants, which is hopefully not the case, since he's already on a power trip, has expressed legitiment psychotic tendencies, is supposed to be on Ambien that he surely isn't taking anymore, and is always giving me a hard time. I'm already looking for a new place to live, this is definitely not the kind of living situation I expected when moving in here.
Is he allowed to enter my room without notice or when I'm not home under the Innkeeper Act? Or are my rights protected even though I share common areas such as the kitchen and bathrooms?
RE: I've never posted on this forum myself ever, but the fact that the network here that I'm using to post this is already flagged as being a culprit for "extreme abuse" is very foreboding

I'm not familiar with the "Innkeeper Act", but an Innkeeper is required to "receive all travelers", and Innkeeper rights like the Innkeeper Lien are in compensation for that. Does your landlord claim right to decide who to rent the room to? If so, your landlord is not an Innkeeper.
